# Xcode Swift sprite-kit SKS file animation works right in the SKS file, but doesn't work on the simulator or iPhone

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, animation, sprite-kit

I am creating an iOS Swift game on Xcode. The game is about a ball and made a moving (left and right) obstacle with a texture animation to go along with it in the SKS file of my level. And in the SKS file, when I clicked the "Animate" button right under the scene editor, the obstacle shows, moves, and works perfectly, but when I ran it on the simulator and on an actual iPhone the movement and animation doesn't do anything or work at all.
Also, there were no error messages, the moving obstacle just don't animate or move.

Is there something I forgot to add or select?

I had worked 2 days on this, looking at other people's code and recreating the scene/obstacle sprite, but none of them worked for me.

I expected the moving obstacle to move left and right and animate with the image I created, but when I ran the game on the simulator and on an actual iPhone nothing happened, the moving obstacle didn't move or animate anything at all.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think you can do everything in the SKS file. I think you have to get the action from the skas file with code, then `run` the action.

Comment: @Sweeper, I saw online instructors and teachers doing it also and it worked great, they said it was the simplest way of doing that.

Comment: the actions will run via the SKS editor, the point of the sks editor is to have as little code as possible (Like unity). I personally would check to make sure that none of your nodes are in a pause state

Comment: @Knight0fDragon, I don't any of my nodes are in pause state because I stated that for every sprite on the screen `sprite.isPaused = false`

Comment: That doesnt mean anything, the system can call ispaused after that on the scene, and every node under it will also pause again

Comment: I found out that when you run it on an actual iPhone 6 sometimes it works when you use a combination of clicks and waits, but it never works on the iPhone XR simulator

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I checked my code over and over again, I never paused the screen or any of the sprites on it

Comment: It doesnt have to be you, sprite kit automatically pauses and unpauses

Comment: @Knight0fDragon, first of all, thanks for your time and energy. So how do you know when the view is paused? Do I have to check if the view is paused in the code or what? How can I prevent this?

Comment: Usually it is anytime the scene enters and leaves the visible play area, so when entering and exiting the app, phone calls, switching apps, etc.  Just set your isPaused on your scene to false sometime after the scene is moved/presented, and you should be ok

Comment: @Knight0fDragon, I add a `view.isPaused = false` when I first entered the scene in the didMove method, that is the only place in which I presented/moved the view, but the problem still isn't fixed and my animations are still not working

Comment: Not view, scene

Comment: @Knight0fDragon, sorry for disturbing again, but `scene!.isPaused = false` also doesn't work when I put it in the didMove method and other places in the GameScene.swift file

Comment: ok, well at least we know that is not what is causing it

Comment: @Knight0fDragon, I found out that if you click the home button twice and switch it back to the game the animations started!

Comment: Huh.... then ur scene is paused

Comment: Well okay, but how do we fix it?

Comment: I just fixed it! I put a `levelNode.isPaused = false` in the load level method and it worked when I opened the app!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I put a `levelNode.isPaused = false` in my custom load level method and it worked when I opened the app!